# Displaying navbar on top of an image does not work properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<div class="container-fluid"  id="_header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img id="mainimg"  src="images/bg1.jpg" alt="background_image" class = "img-responsive mx-auto d-block">
      <!-- <div class="row"> -->
      <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">DROPDOWN<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>   
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="top_left">
          <h4 class="white">FOODZ</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="center">
          <h1 class=" mx-auto d-block text-justify">WELCOME TO FOODZ</h1>
          <h5 class="mx-auto d-block text-justify">WE ARE GROUP OF CENTLEMEN MAKING AWESOME FOOD</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the foods at the left top corner, other two heading need to be centered and nav bar need to be at the right top corner,  Please help me to fix this error thanks in advance

Comment: Please, provide your code in proper way, so that someone can suggest any change.

Comment: give us your tryouts or image

Comment: @DeepakKumar and @ Artem, sorry for the mistake, I add the code now

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid"  id="_header">
<div class="row">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%" class="col-md-12">
      <!-- <div class="row"> -->
     <div style="width: 35%" class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="top_left">
           <h4 class="white">FOODZ</h4>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 50%" class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12" id="center">
             <h1 class=" mx-auto d-block text-justify">WELCOME TO FOODZ</h1>
             <h5 class="mx-auto d-block text-justify">WE ARE GROUP OF CENTLEMEN MAKING AWESOME FOOD</h5>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div style="width: 10%" class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">DROPDOWN<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
       </div>
  </div>
<img id="mainimg"  src="images/bg1.jpg" alt="background_image" class = "img-responsive mx-auto d-block">
</div>
</div>
```

This is the general idea here. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Kash If my answer helps could you please mark it as the answer! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly, you have to add your running code because No one can't understood what you want from your post question but still as my understanding i try something may be this will helpful for you.
```

```css
#_header{
  position:relative;
  background:url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/violet-vector-leaves-circles-backgrounds-for-powerpoint_PdfkI4q.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
.white{
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid"  id="_header">
        <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="top_left">
                            <h4 class="white">FOODZ</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="center">
                  <h1 class=" mx-auto d-block text-justify white">WELCOME TO FOODZ</h1>
                 <h5 class="mx-auto d-block text-justify white">WE ARE GROUP OF CENTLEMEN MAKING AWESOME FOOD</h5>
               </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                         <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">DROPDOWN<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                              <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                                              <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                                              <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>   
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```